# General formula for finding lower/upper limits of iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When calculating the iterated integral over some set A where A:$\{(x_1,x_2,...x_n):ϕ(x_1,x_2,...x_n)=c\}$ , if $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ are all uniquely solvable, is there a generalized "formula" for finding the upper/lower limits for each of the n variables in the iterated integral form?

e.g. finding upper and lower limits for $x,y,z$ when calculating the volume integral of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$: since x can take any value from -R to R, and for each such x, y can take any value from $-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, and for each such x and each such y, z can take any value from $-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$, so its iterated integral is $$\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}dzdydx$$
But is there a general formula for finding the upper/lower limits of such $x,y,z$ based on their functional relation?

I have something in mind but I'm not sure if it's right: first solve for the upper/lower limit of the integral of variable $x_n$ for the function $\phi(x_1,x_2,...x_n)=c$ (as a function of the first (n-1) variables), and then solve for the upper/lower limit of the (n-1)th variable by "extracting" and "eliminating" the terms with $x_n$ in the function $\phi$ (since $x_n$ is uniquely solvable, terms with $x_n$ is..."extractable"?) to form a new function $\phi'(x_1,x_2,...x_{n-1})=c$, and finding limits of variable $x_{n-1}$ in terms of the rest (n-2) variables... and so forth until the last variable.
(It's like always finding the next "lower-dimension" image of the last function, although I don't know the terminology for it)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

No. In 2 dimensions, this gets at what's sometimes called "type I" and "type II" regions. Type I regions are those that are bounded by the graphs of two functions on the top and bottom and vertical lines on the left and right. That corresponds to an integral of the form $\int_a^b \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} F(x, y)\,dy\,dx$. Type II is the same with $x$ and $y$ swapped. The region inside a circle is both type I and type II, but it's easy to make regions that are neither.

You're assuming you're getting intervals at each stage, which need not be the case.

Comment: So the only way of evaluating such integrals is to draw the (n-dimensional) graph of the function(s) and analyze the limits based on its/their intersections case-by-case? But this only works for planes and surfaces... what about higher dimensions?

Comment: Yes, as a practical matter you have to write the region as a finite union of hypervolumes between "iterated graphs". Translating from an abstract oracle or level set function to that description is probably challenging. Very few integrals can be done exactly anyway, the impression textbook problems give notwithstanding, especially iterated integrals.